counting possible coefficient of polynomial
Suppose the roots of the polynomial $x^2 - mx + n$ are positive prime integers (not necessarily distinct). Given that $m < 20,$ how many possible values of $n$ are there?
I can't think of a solution other than brute force, which I already tried and got wrong. Is there a clever way to do this?
I got that $m=r_1+r_2,n=r_1r_2$. Where can I go from that?

Brute force search in this case is not difficult, because as you noted $r_1 + r_2 = m$, which is less than $20$. We only need to identify pairs of prime numbers (not necessarily distinct) whose sum is less than 20. Here they are:
$$(2,2), (2,3), (2,5), (2,7), (2,11), (2,13), (2,17)$$
$$(3,3), (3,5), (3,7), (3,11), (3,13)$$
$$(5,5), (5,7), (5,11), (5,13)$$
$$(7,7), (7,11)$$
That is $18$ pairs. Note that we are not interested in the order of these pairs because we are counting $n=r_1r_2$. Also note that, as user376343 wrote, each of these pairs of prime numbers produces a unique $n$.
